# MySQL insert statement syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a system using PHP and MySQL, and I am trying to insert the data from PHP into my database..

I have been able to get MySQL to insert into two of my tables, but this last one is being a real pain. Here is my error I am recieving:

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL   server version for the right syntax to use near '-roadway_areas, parking_noMeters, noMeter_days, parking_withMeters, withMeters_d' at line 1
```

Here is my code:

```
     mysql_select_db($database_row_application, $dbc);
 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
 if (!$problem) { // If they magicaly got the forum correct
      // Make the insert query
     if (empty($errors)) { // Then insert the information to the database
        $ai = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO applicant_information (firstname, lastname,  address, phone, email, date) 
        VALUES ('$afn', '$aln', '$aa', '$ap', '$ae', '$d')") or die(mysql_error());      //Run the query
     }
     if (empty($errors)) { // Then insert the information to the database
        $ci = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO closing_information (business_name,  address, closure_start_date, closure_end_date, closure_start_time, closure_end_time,  rain_date_start, rain_date_end, signs_requested, emergency_vehicle, meter_serial,   closing_reason) 
        VALUES ('$bn', '$ca', '$cbd', '$cbt', '$ced', '$cet', '$rds', '$rde', '$sr', '$ev', '$ms', '$cr')") or die(mysql_error()); //Run the query
     }
     if (empty($errors)) { // Then insert the information to the database
        $fee = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO fees (non-roadway_areas, parking_noMeters,   noMeter_days, parking_withMeters, withMeters_days, lane_closures, alley_closure, total_fee)   VALUES ('$SDC','$PNMS', '$PNMS', '$PMS', '$PMD', '$VLC', '$AC')") or die(mysql_error());      //Run the query

     }
     if ($ai) { // If it ran
         if ($ci) {
             if ($fee) {
                mysql_close($dbc); // Close the database connection
                // Redirect User
                header("Location: payment.php");

                $_POST = array();
                 }

            // Clear the posted values, or else they'll float in the void f    orever:


        }}}}?>
```

Comment: backquote the table names

Comment: It's because the column name has a hyphen in it. Use the ``

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885497/hyphens-in-column-names-in-mysql-db

Comment: Also turn off [Register Globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) and use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My one column had a hyphen within the name, so I took the hyphen out and put an underscore in its place. Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 3):

It's because the column name has a hyphen in it. Wrap the column names in ` like below:

```
 $fee = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO fees (`non-roadway_areas`, parking_noMeters,   noMeter_days, parking_withMeters, withMeters_days, lane_closures, alley_closure, total_fee)   VALUES ('$SDC','$PNMS', '$PNMS', '$PMS', '$PMD', '$VLC', '$AC')") or die(mysql_error());      //Run the query
```