# Column 'name' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: php, mysql

```
 <?php 
$cid=$_REQUEST['cn'];
 $sid=$_REQUEST['sn'];
 $query="select name,NAME from products a,category b where a.category_id=$cid and a.store_id=$cid and a.category_id=b.ID ";

 $result=  mysqli_query($link, $query)or die(mysqli_error($link));
?>
```

i write simple program,it showing the following error. if i mention name as products.name then it shows unknown column products.name.

the main error is Column 'name' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: And this query is perfectly working

$query="select empno,ename,eadd, esal, edno, edsgcod, dname, dsgnam from tbemployee a,tbdep b,tbdsg c where a.edno=b.dno and a.edsgcod=c.dsgcod";

Comment: try `a.name, b.name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prepend the selected columns since you are doing a query over multiple tables containing columns with the same name eg.:

```
select a.name as prod_name,b.NAME as cat_name 
from products a,category b 
  where a.category_id=$cid 
  and a.store_id=$cid 
  and a.category_id=b.ID
```

Comment: thanks..it is working.  but why we need this ,. and why the that query is running perfetcly which i mention

Comment: I suppose it's because you were selecting columns which aren't shared between all tables. If you have column named "name" in both products and categories, it becomes a problem - the definition becomes ambiguous. If the columns were named eg. "p_name" and "c_name" this problem wouldn't exist.

Comment: and one another ques...why city-name  is giving error while city_name is running

Comment: "-" is not allowed in names of tables nor columns.

Comment: *""-" is not allowed in names of tables nor columns."* - Why not?

Comment: I am sorry, my bad. Here it's explained: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885497/hyphens-in-column-names-in-mysql-db

Comment: thnxxx buddy.u help me out

Comment: *"why **city-name** is giving error while city_name is running"* - They are allowed but discouraged unless wrapped in ticks `\``  . In order words, SQL would interpret that as "city **MINUS** name" ;-) thinking you want to do math. The link above doesn't mention that.