# Laravel 5 storing empty row in database?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently working on a simple blog system for my website, I'm using Laravel 5.5 for this, but I'm having a problem. Whenever I create a new article using the form I created, it is storing a empty row in my database instead of the data from the form...

This is my function to store a article:

```
public function newsStore()
{
    $input = Request::all();

    Article::create($input);

    return $input;
}
```

According to the tutorial that I'm following should this do the trick.. This is the form that I'm currently using:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'news']) !!}
    <!-- Article Title -->
    <div class="form-group row">
        {!! Form::label('title', 'Title:', ['class' => 'col-2 col-form-label']) !!}
        <div class="col-10">
            {!! Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Article Description -->
    <div class="form-group row">
        {!! Form::label('description', 'Description:', ['class' => 'col-2 col-form-label']) !!}
        <div class="col-10">
            {!! Form::text('description', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Article Excerpt -->
    <div class="form-group row">
        {!! Form::label('excerpt', 'Excerpt:', ['class' => 'col-2 col-form-label']) !!}
        <div class="col-10">
            {!! Form::text('excerpt', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Article Image -->
    <div class="form-group row">
        {!! Form::label('image', 'Image:', ['class' => 'col-2 col-form-label']) !!}
        <div class="col-10">
            {!! Form::file('image') !!}
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Article Message -->
    <div class="form-group row">
        {!! Form::label('message', 'Message:', ['class' => 'col-2 col-form-label']) !!}
        <div class="col-10">
            {!! Form::textarea('message', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'rows' => '7']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Article Submit -->
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::button('Add Article', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light float-right', 'type' => 'submit']); !!}
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

This is the route I'm using:

```
Route::post('news', 'DashboardController@newsStore'); // The articles store route
```

This is my model:

```
class Article extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'description',
        'excerpt',
        'image',
        'body',
        'published_at'
    ];
}
```

I have done this once before and have tried to redo it all but can't seem to figure out what is going wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you added $fillable property on the model ?

Comment: return $input; result ? show all inputs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make `create()` work make sure you're using columns with same names. For example, if your column name is `title`, you need to use `title` instead of `news-title` in the form too:

```
{!! Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Comment: I have done this in the Article.php model, like this:
`class Article extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
     'title',
     'description',
     'excerpt',
     'body',
     'published_at'
    ];
}`

Comment: @DionPool I've updated my answer. You have to use the same names in the form to make it work.

Comment: I have changed my post, I have changed everything from "news-title" to "title" for example and when I try posting again. It is still uploading a empty row.

Answer (score 0):

As you use this `Article::create();` it means all your input names should be same as table column name.

**Ex:**

`<input name="title" ...` same be same to column call `news-title` in respective table

---

### If not same

Use [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries)

```
DB::table('table_name')->insert(
    [
        'name' => $input->news-title
        .....
    ]
);
```

---

Read More about [Hyphens in column names in MySQL DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885497/hyphens-in-column-names-in-mysql-db)