# Why did I get an error in phpmyadmin using INSERT INTO and VALUE clauses?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

error message [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1GjW.png) I'm using phpmyadmin in order to use INSERT INTO and the VALUES syntax but I don't know why I'm getting any error. I don't know how your suppose to write your syntax in phpmyadmin using these two clauses. I thought I was suppose to enclose text based characters enclosed in quotes in the VALUE portion of my syntax, but here's my syntax:

INSERT INTO customers (first_name, last_name, mi, nickname, company_name, title, address, city, region, postal_code, country, phone, fax, e-mail, test) VALUES ('Ronald','Mcdonald','Jr','Mc','Mcdonalds INC', 'CEO', 8868 'Pennsylvania Ave', 'Washington DC', 'Maryland', 43276, 'USA', 6782347689, 6783224623, 'dumbfood@losers.com', 'Val'1);

Error Message: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near -mail', 'test') VALUES ('Ronald','Mcdonald','Jr','Mc','Mcdonalds INC', 'CEO', ' at line 1

Table Structure for customers table: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZaxT.png)

Comment: What is the error message,   I suspect the postal code and phone numbers are characters in the database table, and you are treating them as numbers during your INSERT statement

Comment: I have a link that will show you the error message

Comment: have you tried changing your column name e-mail to email or e_mail

Comment: If I type e_mail I get an error that says unknown column in field list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think the single quotes in address and test columns are messed up. Please try the below command. Thanks

INSERT INTO customers
(first_name, last_name, mi, nickname, company_name, title,
address, city, region, postal_code, country, phone, fax, e-mail, test)
VALUES
('Ronald','Mcdonald','Jr','Mc','Mcdonalds INC', 'CEO',
'8868 Pennsylvania Ave', 'Washington DC', 'Maryland', 43276, 'USA', 6782347689, 6783224623, 'dumbfood@losers.com', 'Val1');

Post your table structure if you still face issue.

Comment: This didn't fix my issue. I'll go ahead and show you the table structure.

Comment: I have a picture of my table structure that you can look at.

Comment: I see the column "mi" is of type char(1) and value trying to insert is "Jr". Can you pls try insert a single char  'J' instead of 'Jr' ?

Comment: When I type in a single char for the column "mi" I still get an error when I run it.

Comment: Please see this - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=788ac3a11642335e3eb2d66ddc1632a0

Comment: Using "-" in e-mail is causing the problem i think. Use backtick ( ` ) for e-mail column in insert statement.  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885497/hyphens-in-column-names-in-mysql-db

Comment: Thank you this solved my problem, but I don't know why I had to put quotes around 'e-mail' to be able to get it to work. @praveen

Comment: The doc says if the identifier contains any special characters or reserved word, it needs to be quoted.  Refer the doc - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html  

Rename your column to email and you dont need that backtick.  Cheers.